# Rails 2.3.x equivalent of Rails3 optional route parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In Rails 3 I can do something like this:

```
match "/page(/:section)", :to => 'some_controller#page'
```

And both `/page` and `/page/some_section` will map to some_controller#page

Is there an equivalent of this in Rails 2.3.x ??  I can't seem to find it

I'm currently using two separate route methods like so:

```
map.page          '/page',          :action => 'page'
map.page_section  '/page/:section', :action => 'page'
```

Comment: You can write map.connect "page" and map.connect "page/:section" as separate rules.

Comment: should have mentioned that's what i'm currently using, looking for a more terse syntax

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A parameter becomes optional if you specify a default value.

```
map.page '/page/:section', :action => 'page', :section => "default"
```

If `:section` is present, the value will be the current value. Otherwise, it will default to `default` and the router won't complain.

You can also default the value to `nil`.

```
map.page '/page/:section', :action => 'page', :section => nil
```

Comment: so that I still have params[:section] = 'default' in my controller ?

Comment: can my default value be `nil` ?

Comment: to answer my own question, setting `:section => nil` worked. thx!

Comment: I wasn't sure that `:section => nil` would have worked. Good to know! :)